# Passing text box control to private sub/function

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a series of text boxes that I want to evaluate on form load to change some other elements of the form. Rather than processing them line by line I want to create a function. How can I pass the name of the text box to a function. For example:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Call SetIntialToggleValue(MyTextboxName)

End Sub

Private Sub SetIntialToggleValue(ByRef ControlName As Control)

    MsgBox ControlName.Value

End Sub
```

This give me "Object required" error on the MsgBox line. Which makes me think I'm not passing the textbox control properly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would ask for clarification if I had enough rep to comment, but here are some thoughts:

If you haven't explicitly declared your variable, MyTextboxName, it will be of type variant. You can't pass a variant to an object parameter. This might be enough:

```
dim MyTextBoxName as Control
```

But in this case, you wouldn't be working with names at all. If you want to work with names, you have to change your function. Change the signature to take a string and then use the string as the index into the Controls collection (if there is one on Access Forms):

```
Private Sub SetIntialToggleValue(ByRef ControlName As String)

    MsgBox Form.Controls(ControlName).Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

How about something like the following:

```
Option Explicit
Dim ctl  as Control

Private Sub Form_Load()

    set ctl = Me.MyTextboxName
    Call SetIntialToggleValue(ctl)

End Sub

Private Sub SetIntialToggleValue(ByRef ControlName As Control)

    MsgBox ControlName.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't declare a variable as global if you're only going to use it one method...  That `Dim` statement should go in the `Form_Load()` method.

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/53911-vba-problem-passing-textbox-object-parameter.html). You can declare:

```
Private Sub SetIntialToggleValue(ByRef ControlName As MSForms.TextBox)
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you're not passing in the name of the textbox.  You're passing in the textbox object itself.  You did reference it as a `Control` in your method, but if you're only using textboxes, you could replace `Control` with `Textbox`.  Indeed, `Textbox` is its own type.

Answer (score 0):

The answer as I'm sure you have all figured out is given here:
https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/passing-a-control-as-parameter.213322/

Calling a function with brackets causes the compiler to force a conversion to ByVal which replaces your "control" with the "value" of the control and passes it with the wrong type.

Correct answer is simply SetIntialToggleValue MyTextboxName

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31972315)